# Is doing a factory reset via System Settings the same as a factory reset via recovery?

Tags: factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-s-4

Is doing a factory reset via System Settings the same as a factory reset via Recovery?

Via System Settings in Samsung Galaxy S4:
`System settings > Accounts  > Backup and reset > Personal data > Factory data reset`

Via Recovery:
<kbd>Vol Up</kbd> +  <kbd>Home</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> > ...
*I'm not sure about the exact procedure; Recovery seems to have disappeared from my phone.*

Will these clear the same set of data, or are there slight differences?

Comment: Considering the fact that the phone does reboot when you do that in the Android GUI, I think it's reasonable to assume that it does the same thing -- i.e. it only reboots with some kind of flag that activates the FR functionality in the bootloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never heard there's a difference: factory-reset is factory-reset (which is why both methods are often mentioned alternatively to each other: if you still can power up your device manually, you can use the corresponding item in the *Settings* menu -- otherwise, you can go via the [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode)).

Usually, the menu item in *Settings* says something like "Reset to factory defaults", while the corresponding entry in recovery says "Wipe data and caches".

Now, what is a factory-reset, in technical terms? Resetting all settings to the defaults of the currently installed ROM, while deleting all data and user-installed apps.

How is that done? By...

- wiping `/data` (user-apps and data, plus Dalvik Cache) and
- wiping `/cache` (app cache)

Now comes the circular reasoning: Isn't that what the corresponding entry in recovery says -- "wiping data and caches"?

Comment: depends on the device. for some recent models (that i work on) this two aren't same. after i pinpoint that, i will try to add a detailed answer.

Comment: That would be interesting. All I know is that on some devices/ROMs the factory-reset menu entry offers to also wipe SD cards (internal and external) with a factory-reset. But I couldn't find out whether in those cases the recovery manu didn't offer the same.

Comment: i just asked a question, http://android.stackexchange.com/q/57814/20859 where i have detailed a scenerio

Comment: That does not necessarily mean the two factory reset methods are different. There are multiple reports around of "incomplete factory-resets", where the first run seems to have not done its job completely, but a second run (from the very same place) finally did (see e.g. [here](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Android/Unknown-error-code-quot-24-quot/td-p/274896/page/2)).