# When extactly does the hangouts_video_call.ogg extracted from hangout.apk?

Tags: apk, ringtone, google-hangouts, optimization, odex

Two ringtones are extracted from Hangout.apk to */storage/ringtones* folder during some system setup phase.

To analyze that,  I manually deleted the ringtone files from my_files >> Ringtone. Now, no hangout ringtone in *settings->sound->ringtone*.

Then, done "*Factory reset*" from settings. Now, hangout ringtones didn't restored.

Now, i did "Factory reset" from recovery mode.Those hangout ringtones are restored again. That is visible through MyFiles as well as RingtoneChooser.
So, it turned out that "Factory reset" is somewhat different between "recovery mode" and from "settings".

I need to know when extactly does the hangouts_video_call.ogg extracted from hangout.apk? How can i find the log ? Any clue will be highly helpful.

Comment: That does not necessarily mean the two factory reset methods are different. There are multiple reports around of "incomplete factory-resets", where the first run seems to have not done its job completely, but a second run (from the very same place) finally did.

Comment: this in not happening once. this is happening always :|

Comment: Which still is no proof the one way or the other. If it always happens when running it from *Settings*, but always works fine on the first run from recovery (without running it from *Settings* before), *that* would be something different.

Comment: Why do you need to know? What are you trying to achieve?